# PHP: Replace apenas na primeira palavra repetida

Tags: php, replace

Olá, por exemplo, tenho a frase:

> Meu nome é "Vitor", o nome "dele" "é" "Vitor", "seu" nome "é" "Vitor"

Eu utilizo um **preg_replace** para trocar todas as palavras que estão entre aspas pela palavra "abacaxi".
Ficaria:

> Meu nome é "abacaxi", o nome "abacaxi" "abacaxi" "abacaxi", "abacaxi" nome "abacaxi" "abacaxi"

Porém, como eu posso realizar esse replace apenas nas primeiras palavras repetidas que estão entre aspas? Exemplo:

> Meu nome é "abacaxi", o nome "abacaxi" "abacaxi" "Vitor", "abacaxi" nome "é" "Vitor"

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer melhor sua duvida, veja: na sentença: **Meu nome é Vitor, o nome dele é Vitor, seu nome é Vitor**, se fossemos ocultar somente a primeira ocorrência de cada repetição, ficaria: **Meu abacaxi abacaxi abacaxi, o nome dele é Vitor, seu nome é Vitor** e não **Meu nome é abacaxi, o nome abacaxi abacaxi Vitor, abacaxi nome é Vitor** como exemplificado por você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser que tenha uma função especifica para isso, porém é fácil de fazer na mão.

Supondo o texto:

> Meu nome é "Vitor", o nome "dele" "é" "Vitor", "seu" nome "é" "Vitor"

Podemos fazer simplesmente:

Encontrar o `"`, encontrando obtenha a palavra até o próximo `"`. Esta palavra verifique se já foi substituída anteriormente, se não substitui e adiciona esta palavra na lista de "já substituído".

---

Isto é mais para fins didáticos, mas claramente pode fazer isso de maneira mais organizada.

```
$substituto = "abacaxi";

$posicaoInicio = -1;
$posicaoFim = -1;
$dicionario = [];


while($posicaoInicio !== false && $posicaoFim !== false){

    $posicaoInicio = strpos($texto, '"', $posicaoFim + 1);
    $posicaoFim = strpos($texto, '"', $posicaoInicio + 1);

    $palavraTamanho = ($posicaoFim - $posicaoInicio) - 1;
    $palavra = substr($texto, $posicaoInicio + 1, $palavraTamanho);

    if($posicaoInicio !== false 
       && $posicaoFim !== false 
       && in_array($palavra, $dicionario, true) === false){

        $dicionario[] = $palavra;

        $texto = substr_replace($texto, $substituto, $posicaoInicio + 1, $palavraTamanho);

        $diferencaTamanho = strlen($substituto) - $palavraTamanho;
        $posicaoFim = ($posicaoFim + $diferencaTamanho) + 1;

    }

}
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cbf23e2ee4421d302d6e817d7ecdcbd7638eb67c)**

A ideia é bem simplória, primeiro fazemos encontramos o inicio e o fim da palavra alvo, ou seja a palavra que está entre as aspas, para isso usamos:

```
 $posicaoInicio = strpos($texto, '"', $posicaoFim + 1);
 $posicaoFim = strpos($texto, '"', $posicaoInicio + 1);
```

O strpos encontrará a primeira ocorrência a partir do offset, portanto, supondo:

> Meu nome é "Vitor"

A primeira aspa (inicio) é 12, então precisamos procura a outra a partir do 13, que será encontrado na posição 18.

Nós então sabemos que a primeira palavra está entre o 13º até o 17º byte, *neste caso*. Logico, precisamos excluir as aspas, para isso usamos:

```
$palavraTamanho = ($posicaoFim - $posicaoInicio) - 1;
```

Isso será utilizado para que 18 - 12 (= 6), então subtraímos 1, tornando 5. Esse é o tamanho da palavra.

Então obtemos a palavra:

```
$palavra = substr($texto, $posicaoInicio + 1, $palavraTamanho);
```

O inicio é 12, porém 12 inclui as aspas, portanto temos que adicionar 1, assim pegando os 5 bytes, correspondente a `Vitor`, sem aspas.

Agora precisamos saber se a palavra existe e se ela já não foi substituída, então:

```
$posicaoInicio !== false 
&& $posicaoFim !== false 
&& in_array($palavra, $dicionario, true) === false
```

Isso irá fazer com que ele tenha que ter achado as duas aspas e a palavra não pode está inserida em `$dicionario`, que é uma array que iremos preencher com as palavras já substituídas. Ou seja, todas as palavras que já conhecemos (que está no dicionário) já foi trocada. ;)

Se estiver tudo certo e não tiver sido substituído fazermos isto. Adicionamos a palavra no nosso dicionário:

```
$dicionario[] = $palavra;
```

Agora trocamos a palavra no texto usando:

```
$texto = substr_replace($texto, $substituto, $posicaoInicio + 1, $palavraTamanho);
```

Isso irá fazer com que coloque insira o abacaxi a partir do 13º byte com um tamanho de 5 dígitos. Ou seja, trocará o `Vitor` por `abacaxi`, ele irá remover o `Vitor` e adicionará o `abacaxi` em seu lugar.

Se você perceber, existe um problema, o `abacaxi` é maior, em quantidade de caracteres, do que o `Vitor`, por isso precisamos calcular o `$posicaoFim`, afinal nós precisamos saber qual foi a última aspa identificada.

Por isso usamos:

```
$diferencaTamanho = strlen($substituto) - $palavraTamanho;
$posicaoFim = ($posicaoFim + $diferencaTamanho) + 1;
```

Isso irá calcular a diferença do tamanho de ambos os textos (`Vitor` e `abacaxi`) e irá ajustar a última `"`. Matematicamente a diferença entre os dois é de 7 - 5 (=2). Então precisamos contar com as aspas, acrescentando 1, no total ficará 18 + 2 + 1 (= 21). A última aspa está na 21º posição.

Agora, fazemos isso de novo, porém com o `dele`, assim por diante.

---